# Outlook Calendar Rest API (create meeting using /me/events request with change organizer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, calendar, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I am using Outlook Calendar Rest API. I have define scope like:

SCOPES = [
             'outlook.office.com/mail.read',

'outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite'
         ]

using request like:
REQUEST = https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/

I am able to fetch events of calendar and also able to create a simple meeting on calendar using Rails framework. Now I want to change my organizer using this request /me/events. Is there any way to sort it out?

Comment: Hi @Zeeshan Rehman, do i need single sign on to implement this feature?, could u please share document you followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to change the organizer of a meeting by api, or even through Outlook application. Please see the following links:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Best-practices-when-using-the-Outlook-Calendar-D93F72D3-2361-4E0D-8D6A-5C4939C17F39

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4401-outlook-change-meeting-organizer-owner.html

Comment: Thanks, @AidaNow but it should be facility to change the organizer with in a calendar.